# Nuxt 3 props value not receiving first time on mounted method

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vue-props

I am working on nuxt 3 and I have an issue with props. I am passing one object from the parent component to the child component using props but when I console those props then the object seems blank but if I put the same console under the `setTimeout` function inside the mounted method then it is working fine. Please check the below code for more ideas.

**Parent component**

```js
<template>
  <ChildComponent
    :form-data="formData.childData"
  />
<script setup>
const formData = reactive({
 ...
 ...
});

onMounted(() => {
  const { data, error } = await useFetch("my-api-url");
  if (data.value) {
    formData = data.value;
  }
});
</script>
</template>
```

**Child component**

```js
<template>
  {{ }}
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  formData: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
    default: "",
  },
});

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(props.formData); // **Receiving blank object**

  setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(props.formData); // **Receiving perfectly **
  }, 1000) 
});
</script>
</template>
```

I have tried to use async function on onMounted `onMounted( async () => { ... })` but not working

Kindly please help me on this if there is any standard option to use props on onMounted without any `setTimeout` function

Answer (score 0):

Child component is mounted before `await useFetch("my-api-url")` is called at Parent component, so while `useFetch()` is getting data you will get a blank object as prop.

If you want to listen when props are changed you could use `watch`:

```js
watch(() => props.formData, (old, new) => {
    console.log(new);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Just confirming is there any other way or this is one of the standard way?

Answer (score 0):

You Should get your response first before rendering the child component

```html
<template>
  <ChildComponent
  v-if="formDataReady" 
    :form-data="formData.childData"
  />
<script setup>
const formData = reactive({
 ...
 ...
});

const formDataReady = ref(false)

onMounted(() => {
    try {
      const { data, error } = await useFetch("my-api-url");
      if (data.value) {
        formData = data.value;
        formDataReady.value = true
      }
    } catch (err) {
      // handle error
    }
});
</script>
</template>
```

Comment: It does not work. Please check the question my API call is in parent component